# How to change multiple headers in a table using Powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, web-scraping, html-parsing, powershell-4.0

I am trying to change multiple header names within my code that is pulling the **Team Statistics** table from [this site](https://www.hockey-reference.com/leagues/NHL_2020.html)
I am unsure where to manually change them in my code.

For example, I tried manually changing header 8, GF to GFPG in the line where I add the '**TEAM**' header, but I get the error:

> Exception calling "Add" with "2" argument(s): "Item has already been added. Key in dictionary: 'GF'  Key being added: 'GF'"
>   At C:\NHLScraper.ps1:32 char:5
>   +     $objHash.Add($headers[$j],$rowdata[$j])

My code:

```
$url = "https://www.hockey-reference.com/leagues/NHL_2020.html"

#getting the data
$data = Invoke-WebRequest $url

#grab the third table
$table = $data.ParsedHtml.getElementsByTagName("table") | Select -skip 2 | Select -First 1


#get the rows of the Team Statistics table
$rows = $table.rows

#get table headers
$headers = $rows.item(1).children | select -ExpandProperty InnerText

#count the number of rows
$NumOfRows = $rows | Measure-Object

#Manually injecting TEAM header
$headers = @($headers[0];'TEAM';$headers[1..($headers.Length-1)])

#enumerate the remaining rows (we need to skip the header row) and create a custom object
$out = for ($i=2;$i -lt $NumofRows.Count;$i++) {
 #define an empty hashtable
 $objHash=[ordered]@{}
 #getting the child rows
 $rowdata = $rows.item($i).children | select -ExpandProperty InnerText 
 for ($j=0;$j -lt $headers.count;$j++) {
    #add each row of data to the hash table using the correlated table header value
    $objHash.Add($headers[$j],$rowdata[$j])
  }

  #turn the hashtable into a custom object
  [pscustomobject]$objHash
}

$out | Select TEAM,AvAge,GP,W,L,OL,PTS,PTS%,GF,GA,SOW,SOL,SRS,SOS,TG/G,EVGF,EVGA,PP,PPO,PP%,PPA,PPOA,PK%,SH,SHA,PIM/G,oPIM/G,S,S%,SA,SV%,SO -SkipLast 1 | Export-Csv -Path "C:\$((Get-Date).ToString("'NHL Stats' yyyy-MM-dd")).csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: I just ran your code a few times with 9th element being GFPG and no errors. Are you sure you're getting that error? Is it possible you were doing that without creating a new hashtable each time you looped?

Comment: Where did you change it? After I implemented your solution, I still don't know where to change GF to GFPG

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a condition to check if the key has already been added and if so, update it or ignore it,

```
if (!$objHash.Contains(headers[$j]))
    $objHash.Add($headers[$j],$rowdata[$j])

else
    $objHash[$headers[$j]] = $rowdata[$j] # Overwrite values
```

But after looking at your code a few times, this doesnt make sense,

```
$out = for ($i=2;$i -lt $NumofRows.Count;$i++) {
 #define an empty hashtable
 $objHash=[ordered]@{}         # Overwritten each loop???
 #getting the child rows
 $rowdata = $rows.item($i).children | select -ExpandProperty InnerText 
 for ($j=0;$j -lt $headers.count;$j++) {
    #add each row of data to the hash table using the correlated table header value
    $objHash.Add($headers[$j],$rowdata[$j])   # Dictionary cannot have duplicate keys
  }

  #turn the hashtable into a custom object
  [pscustomobject]$objHash    # what do you do with this?
}
```

You are looping over x number of times and each time you are overwriting the $objHash. only thing that would be returned is whats created in the last loop.

**Suggested Solution**

You can use another variable to keep track of all the hashtables you are creating along with making sure **duplicate keys are not inserted** that would throw the exception.

```
# If you want to change the header value from GF to GFPG, you can do that in the place you have defined $headers


#get table headers
$headers = $rows.item(1).children | select -ExpandProperty InnerText
$headers = $headers | % { if ($_ -eq "GF") { "GFPG" }  else { $_ }} 

#count the number of rows
$NumOfRows = $rows | Measure-Object

#Manually injecting TEAM header
$headers = @($headers[0];'TEAM';$headers[1..($headers.Length-1)])

#enumerate the remaining rows (we need to skip the header row) and create a custom object
$allData = @{}
$out = for ($i=2;$i -lt $NumofRows.Count;$i++) {
 #define an empty hashtable
 $objHash=[ordered]@{}
 #getting the child rows
 $rowdata = $rows.item($i).children | select -ExpandProperty InnerText 
 for ($j=0;$j -lt $headers.count;$j++) {
    #add each row of data to the hash table using the correlated table header value
    $objHash[$headers[$j]] = $rowdata[$j]        
  }

  #turn the hashtable into a custom object
  [pscustomobject]$objHash
  $allData.Add($i, $objHash)
}
```

I used `$AllData` with `i` as the key to store each of those results that can later be accessed.

Comment: so if I add your solution above, where will I be able to change the desired headers?

Comment: Just to add to the solution above, you can actually use `$objHash."$($headers[$j])" = $rowdata[$j]` if you don't need to perform actions based on the fact the key already exists. That statement will either add or edit the existing item without additional check.

Comment: @SagePourpre might you know where I'd be able to change the headers? Still stuck on that after adding Jawad's new variables

Comment: I just updated the code to include the place where you can update the Headers variable. You can use the replace method to replace GF with GFPG. @jackrabbit let me know if this helps

Comment: @SagePourpre incorporated your suggestion to the key assignment

Comment: @jackrabbit found an issue with my suggestion. Replaceing GF with GFPG replaces all instances of GF (whether its part of the string or full string). I updated the answer above to make sure it only replaces string that matches in its entirety